# Jquery filter function not responding to :not() pseudo-selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, pseudo-class

So I have a jquery keyup/filter function filtering a large table, to simulate a 'search' feature by keyword. It's all one table with headers and topic rows included. I'm trying to get the function to ignore topic rows, which are in a class 'hideTopic,' which I attempted to exclude with the :not() pseudo-selector. At the moment, if someone searches the wrong keyword, it's returning every single topic row (see picture below).

```
            $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                $("#searchable tr:not(.hideTopic)").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                });
            });
```

[image]

```
<html>
<table id="searchable" class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                  <td><br><br><br><p class="header" id="PVInsuranceVerification">Insurance Verification</p></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
                </thead>
                 <thead>
                  <tr class="hideTopic">
                    <th scope="col" >Topic</th>
                    <th scope="col" >PDF</th>
                    <th scope="col" >Video</th>
                    <th scope="col" >HealthStream</th>
                  <td class="center"></td></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr><td>Adding/Updating Insurance<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Provider_to_Patient_Contact/Adding-Updating-Terminating_Insurance.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=d1e03099-c094-4100-8001-ecc0c7f994b1" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6NTA6NDQmY2lkPWE0M2UwYjAwLTc1ZjktZTgxMS1hNjIxLTAwNTA1NmIxNTIyYiZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Batch Eligibility<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Batch_Eligibility.pdf">PDF</a></td><td class="center"></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Eligibility<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Provider_to_Patient_Contact/Eligibility_-_Single_Patient_at_Time_of_Service.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=b957bb26-2814-495f-94ef-5cbdf1efc886" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6NTE6MzkmY2lkPTA2MTFjZjY0LWNhZjgtZTgxMS1iZjI5LTAwNTA1NmIxN2M4MCZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>eCW Eligibility Verification<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=7291fc54-00b2-4279-a36f-f203834d4b91" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>eCW Eligibility Verification (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=65f2b0db-0013-41ad-a9bf-5169bb7678d0" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Eligibility - Single Patient at Time of Service<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Eligibility_-_Single_Patient_at_Time_of_Service.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=129f71df-b17b-4c65-b6ff-6b2aa8a9971f129f71df-b17b-4c65-b6ff-6b2aa8a9971f" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6NTE6MzkmY2lkPTA2MTFjZjY0LWNhZjgtZTgxMS1iZjI5LTAwNTA1NmIxN2M4MCZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Eligibility Verification Common Mistakes and Best Practices<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/MM_PROJECT_Eligibility_Overview_ILT_v2CE.pptx">PPTX</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=efee1c3d-b9b8-4a2a-beb0-dea3494cce68" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Eligibility Verification Common Mistakes and Best Practices (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11e_Eligibility_Verification_Common_Mistakes_and_Best_Practices.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=65f2b0db-0013-41ad-a9bf-5169bb7678d0" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>How to Submit eSAF for Passport OneSource Access<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/eSAF_for_Passport_OneSource_How_to_JA.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Insurance Requested Process<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Provider_to_Patient_Contact/Insurance_Requested_Process.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=9f4ffd55-cc80-4bff-8465-cc8d67a3b840" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6NTI6NTQmY2lkPTkzOTJmMGViLWQwZjgtZTgxMS1iYjYwLTAwNTA1NmIxNjgwYyZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Insurance Requested Process (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11e_Insurance_Requested_Process.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=2ebf0296-70d7-48b5-8639-cd3ba3349ec8" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Interpreting Passport Verifications<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=eacf514c-5712-4356-95f1-a77610d570c8" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Iplan Selection<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=c75bb339-0377-4430-9181-04f9cc52b984" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>MVA Case Management What You Need to Know<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=4f76de39-6f82-4fa0-a597-af068b5dfaf8" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>MVA Case Management Process<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=bb83be0e-8b5d-455d-9587-e8b1196e47b1" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Payer Website Request Form<span style="display:none;">Insurance Verification</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Payor_Access_Request.pdf">PDF</a></td><td class="center"></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <thead>
                      <td><br><br><br><p class="header" id="ptDemoEntry">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</p></td><td></td><td></td><td><a href="#topPage" style="color:#1e345d;">^Back to Top</a></td>
                  </thead>
                     <thead>
                      <tr class="hideTopic">
                        <th scope="col" >Topic</th>
                        <th scope="col" ">Docs</th>
                        <th scope="col" >Videos</th>
                        <th scope="col" >HealthStream</th>
                      <td class="center"></td></tr>
                    </thead>
                  <tr><td>Adolescent Portal Consent Documentation<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Adolescent_Portal_Consent_Documentation.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a></a></td></tr> 
                  <tr><td>Demographic Entry Standard<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Demographic_Entry_Standards.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=145b5a74-5af2-4e49-bde4-9044c884c34a" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6MzU6MjAmY2lkPWI2NzM2ZGE2LTlhZmMtZTgxMS1iOTI5LTAwNTA1NmIxMzBlZiZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Demographic Entry Standards (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11e_Demographic_Entry_Standards.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=2828d566-f5fa-482c-83d2-864e33633b2b" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Duplicate Account Process<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/FOS_Duplicate_Account_Process.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=8562444e-91c7-49c3-bbf9-43c24e50edba" target="_blank">Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="" target="_blank"></a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Duplicate Account Process (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e_Duplicate_Account_Process.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=3f5e4ddc-5959-48b0-9c63-d5e964a1c46d" target="_blank">Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="" target="_blank"></a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Duplicate Account Process FAQ<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Duplicate_Account_Process_FAQs.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="" target="_blank"></a></td><td class="center"><a href="" target="_blank"></a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Entering Email Addresses<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Entering_Email_Address.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=b5a890a3-9f91-42ed-84d6-7b9be425fc4b" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6NDU6MTgmY2lkPWQ3Y2ExNjRjLTZiZjktZTgxMS1hNmMzLTAwNTA1NmIxNDFjYyZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Entering Email Addresses (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11e_Entering_Email_Address.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=a126a73c-f026-4e28-bb68-678e7ef68ea8" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Entering Patient Demographics<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Entering_Patient_Demographics.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=9932eb38-2890-480f-8a29-e2a6812cfe33" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6Mzk6MjImY2lkPTI1YTRiNTc5LTc4ZjktZTgxMS1iMzQxLTAwNTA1NmIxNDU2YSZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Entering Patient Demographics (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11e_Entering_Patient_Demographics.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Entering Out of Office Visits (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11e_Entering_Out_of_Office_Visits.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=0c5d51e0-7566-4b5d-a169-d0c006195233" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Patient Demographic Log<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Patient_Demographic_Log.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>SOGI<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/SOGI.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=b013b257-1f83-4c7c-9bd6-e1d3106f7fdb" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6NDY6NTYmY2lkPWY3NTFiZjAwLTc0ZjktZTgxMS1iOTA1LTAwNTA1NmIxMGUzMyZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>SOGI (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11e_SOGI.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=b110d072-9632-4a4b-b14e-36c5d33ca826" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Adding, Updating, Terminating Insurance<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/FOS_Adding_Updating_Terminating_Insurance_DH_10.20.20.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=aeb6ad6d-6783-4c07-a1ab-e0c893e0084c" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTQ6NTA6NDQmY2lkPWE0M2UwYjAwLTc1ZjktZTgxMS1hNjIxLTAwNTA1NmIxNTIyYiZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Adding, Updating, Terminating Insurance (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e_Adding-Updating-Terminating_Insurance.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=98f7c963-8d79-48e4-aa92-3981ce8b2f00" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Adolescent Portal Consent Documentation<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Prior_to_Patient_Visit/Adolescent_Portal_Consent_Documentation.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a></a></td></tr> 
                  <tr><td>Validation - Check In<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Check_In.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=8edd6899-4132-415b-b84c-2ec2d6fd73df" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTU6MTI6MDEmY2lkPWIxZDdlYTNkLWM5ZjgtZTgxMS04N2FlLTAwNTA1NmIxN2UzNCZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Check In (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11e_Check_In_done.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=af496e2b-91da-483d-a915-a952cb25f1ba" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Completing the Medicare Secondary Payor (MSP) Form<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/1006a-MEDICARE STATUS QUESTIONNAIRE ATTACHMENT A.docx" target="_blank">Doc</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=248de31e-9d05-4784-87c7-19a85e60d6c7" target="_blank"><!--UPDATED-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDQtMjNUMTU6MDg6MjMmY2lkPTJkMjFjYzQ0LWNiODktZTcxMS1hYjk4LTAwNTA1NmIxMmI5YyZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Completing the Medicare Secondary Payor (MSP) Form (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=8c8babb8-5515-4b2a-98b8-482533fd2f2a" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Patient Registration Form - Spanish<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Patient_Registration_Form_eCW_2011_Spanish.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Patient Registration Form (eCW)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Patient_Registration_Form_eCW_2011.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Percent Copays<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Percent_CoPays.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=d889a5ed-f7be-4da1-a726-23b6082f76d4" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTU6MTQ6MTImY2lkPWE2OGU4NDJlLWQ0ZjgtZTgxMS1hYjc2LTAwNTA1NmIxMzcyMSZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Percent CoPays (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11e_Percent_CoPays.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=1f509134-2f99-4e0d-812d-976c6bdd9fc1" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Telephone Consent<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Telephone_Consent.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=f2a9f253-6f3a-4044-8859-c18b44f67106" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTU6MTU6MDYmY2lkPTA1NWEyM2U2LTE2MDMtZTkxMS05MmMwLTAwNTA1NmIxN2UzNCZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Telephone Encounters (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11E_Telephone Encounters.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=3feb4d81-083f-4fb0-9706-17afe0d90acb" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Troubleshooting - Insurance Eligibility<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Troubleshooting_–_Insurance_Eligibility.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTktMDItMTJUMTU6MTY6MTAmY2lkPTQ3NmVhZTc1LTI2ZmUtZTgxMS1iNjUyLTAwNTA1NmIxMDY1NyZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Adding I-Plans for Self Pay Inpatients/ER Patients<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Adding_iPlans_for_Self_Pay_In-Patient_ER_Patients.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=80dcff0a-e36d-48e5-b5cb-328802c7c67d" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTgtMTItMTlUMjE6NTA6NTMmY2lkPWU4NzM1OGEzLWNlZjgtZTgxMS1iOTA1LTAwNTA1NmIxMGUzMyZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Adding I-Plans for Self Pay Inpatients/ER Patients (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11e_Adding_iPlans_for_Self_Pay_In-Patient_ER Patients.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=759c91b9-ea7d-45c4-958a-0e8604dbcf37" target="_blank">Video</a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Alerts: Billing, Global, Insurance, Meaningful Use<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Alerts-Billing,_Global,_Insurance,_Meaningful_Use.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="http://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=7b733853-7840-473f-ac13-ee8136f9b09a" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTgtMTItMTlUMjE6NTE6MjAmY2lkPTRkZjg4YmEzLTcwZjktZTgxMS1iMzc5LTAwNTA1NmIxMGYwMiZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Alerts: Billing, Global, Insurance, and Meaningful Use (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11e_Alerts – Billing_Global_Insurance_and_Meaningful_Use_done.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Appointment Right Chart Panel<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Appointment_Right_Chart_Panel.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=cbbb8f74-18e2-415e-b8ec-68bc2d08e443" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTgtMTItMTlUMjE6NTI6MzAmY2lkPTVhMGI2MjUwLWEyZmMtZTgxMS1hODFlLTAwNTA1NmIxNDk2MSZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Appointment Right Chart Panel (eCW 11e)<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/11e/11e_Appointment_Right_Chart_Panel_done.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=306c9561-1a6f-4ab1-a55c-15b0d0897efe" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE--></a></td><td class="center"></td></tr>
                  <tr><td>Validation - Terminating a Patient<span style="display:none;">Patient Demographic Entry/Validation</span></td><td class="center"><a href="training/Patient_Check_In/Terminating_a_Patient.pdf" target="_blank">PDF</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://mediaconnect.app.medcity.net/embed?id=024a9eb4-4d23-40bd-876d-e67abd7297bb" target="_blank"><!--UPDATE-->Video</a></td><td class="center"><a href="https://www.healthstream.com/hlc/common/course/quicklinks.aspx?oid=a86b970c-a5b3-da11-8139-000423acef71&quickLink=YT0xJnRzPTIwMTgtMTItMTlUMjE6NTI6NTEmY2lkPTI0ZjI2NzAyLWI4ZjktZTgxMS1iYjYwLTAwNTA1NmIxNjgwYyZjdj0w" target="_blank">Course</a></td></tr>
                  
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your html, without it's very hard to test

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I included a piece of the table--too big to include all of it.

Comment: `hideTopic` is an id... Not a class. `$("#searchable tr:not(#hideTopic)")` should work. Notice there is no single quotes.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I was swapping things around just trying to get the pseudo-selector to work on anything at all. it didn't work as either a class or id, but if I added a simpler js line just affecting its css-- $("#searchable tr:not('#hideTopic')").css()-- it would work

Comment: that's a type ; just replace class with id selector `$("#searchable tr:not('#hideTopic')")`

Answer (score 1):

your jquery function is not correct, since hideTopic is an id not a class,
please use the following code instead

```
 $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                $("#searchable tr:not(#hideTopic)").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                });
            });
```

Note also that **[:not](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/:not)** pseudo selector is used without quotes,

Comment: It still doesn't seem to be working. I'd been messing with the id v class and accidentally posted the original question with those mixed up, but even after that fix (and removing single quotes) it still doesn't work.